# 0 length ObserveableArray when accessed inside function

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a model class with a few functions (methods) attached to it.  When I look at the length of an observable array outside of the functions the length is returned correctly.  But when I look at the observablearray inside a function of the modelclass it always returns 0.  But if I access an item inside the observablearray by index inside the function it returns the correct item.  Why would length always be 0?

```
    function ModelView(data) {
      var self = this;


      self.items= ko.observableArray(data.items);
      var test = self.items().length; //shows correct number
      self.EditRule = function (product) {
        for(var i=0; i<self.items().length; i++)
              //dosuff but self.items().length is always 0


      }
    }
```

I found a work around by adding an additional property into the viewmodel like so:

```
     self.itemslength = ko.observable(self.items().length);
```

obviously my actual issue is much more complicated but the loop is doing a compare of items against parameters passed in to make sure somethings are valid. self.items is basically a masterlist.

Comment: might have to put it in a jsFiddle. Seems fine above.

Comment: What happens if you replace the body of the loop with `console.log(i)` (I mean really replace, not just stick the log at the beginning)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `ko.utils.arrayForEach` for iterating over your observableArray:

```
function ModelView(data) {
      var self = this;
      self.items = ko.observableArray(data.items);
      var test = self.items().length; //shows correct number
      self.EditRule = function () {
          ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function(item){
              if (item.name === "2"){
                  // For example
                  console.log(self.items().length); //will be 3
                  self.items.remove(item);
                  console.log(self.items().length); //will be 2
              }
          });
      }
 }

var myData = {
    items : [{id: 0, name: "0"},{ id: 1, name: "1"}, {id: 2, name: "2"}]
}

var myModelView = new ModelView(myData);
ko.applyBindings(myModelView);
```

with this html i tested:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: EditRule">EditRule</a>
```

You can also use the vanilla for loop if you like: Its very similar to your own attempt but you might have a mistake somewhere else.

```
function ModelView(data) {
      var self = this;
      self.items = ko.observableArray(data.items);
      var test = self.items().length; //shows correct number
      self.EditRule = function () {
          for(var i =0; i < self.items().length; i++){
              if (self.items()[i].name === "2"){
                  // For example
                  console.log(self.items().length); //will be 3
                  self.items.remove(self.items()[i]);
                  console.log(self.items().length); //will be 2
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I marked it as the answer because it is a viable solution.  But what I don't get is why can't I get the length of an observableArray in a "method/function" of the view model class it belongs too.  That seems like a bug.  Could you explain? Because it does not seem to be a scope issue (unless it is JS specific type issue).